# Get the string value of numbers in EventLogFile

Tags: event, eventlogfile, shield

I'm working on a parser for Shield events ([**EventLogFile**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm)).
I want to get the string value for **APP_TYPE** in Logout event:

> Type:Number
>
> Description: The application type that was in use upon logging out.
>
> Example Values:
>
> 1007: SFDC Application
>
> 1014: Live Agent
>
> 2501: CTI
>
> 2514: OAuth
>
> 3475: SFDC Partner Portal

How can i get the mapping between the numbers to the string values?

Comment: You can refer this trailhead: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/event_monitoring/units/event_monitoring_query

Comment: i'm familier with this guide, there is no answer to my question in it.

Comment: In the trailhead there is an example of ReportExport, you just replace that with 'Logout' and try to parse the data

Comment: I know how to get the data from salesforce and parse the CSV, the problem is with fields like APP_TYPE, I need to know how to find the string value from the given number.

Comment: put your code whatever you have tried so far, so that community members can help you

Comment: there is no need to share my code, the question is simple - in case that I have APP_TYPE field with value 2514 for example, how can I understand that the APP_TYPE is OAuth?

Comment: @kobi - Are you looking for a list of APP_TYPE (cannot find one) The field type is number so I don't think the text comes across and is there for illustration only. Then again I have not worked with event log files. Can you please clarify?

Comment: yes, I'm looking for this list.